# Are "ties" considering "successful" checks in Firefly Adventures?

Tags: untagged

So, for example in combat, ties mean that both targets take damage.

However, the Martial Artist says

> Reroll successful Brawling against Martial Artist.

Does this mean, that since *both* targets, including the Martial Artist, takes a wound, is that a success, and therefore must be re-rolled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you will need to reroll.**

On page 4 of the [rulebook](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/158735/firefly-adventures-rulebook):

> To make a Skill Test, roll the number of dice pictured and add all your available Skill Points of the appropriate type to your dice’s total. **If your dice roll plus your Skill is equal to or higher than the Skill Test’s Target, it’s a Success.** If it’s lower, it’s a Failure.

The rulebook clearly defines rolls as having a binary outcome, success or failure, and groups ties as a success for the player. In the case of a tie with the Martial Artist (i.e.: a success), you would need to reroll.

Comment: Note that that's for skill tests, not for Brawling, as I noted in the comments to my answer.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Brawling is a skill test. Page 4: "Whether a bare knuckle Brawl or open gunplay, enough Fight Skill will get you through." Page 8: "In a Brawl, both the combatants roll a die and add the Fight Skill on their Character Card."

Comment: While I agree with the conclusion, I'll note that the text leaves room for the opposing viewpoint, IMO, by not coming out and labelling it "skill test" -- it could just be a contested roll that uses one's Fight Skill as the base number.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Equality counts as success (hence the wounding of the opponent; success = inflict wound), just like in regular skill tests, shooting, etc.

Note in the rulebook [v1.1 on BGG](https://firefly.gf9games.com/brigandsbrowncoats/FAQ/Firefly_Adventures_Rulebook_v1_1.pdf), the image of the Martial Artist shows his text as "Heroes must reroll Hits against Martial Artist.", further substantiating this reading of "success.

Every other reference to "success" in the rulebook includes equality as a success; the brawling section of the rules never uses the word success, only talking about wounding (or not) as the possible outcome. There is no other available interpretation that fits with the body of rules text.

I've put in an email query to GF9 on May 23 for an official word (as well as [posting in the BGG forums](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/32059399) -- with predictable responses there so far).

Comment: Could you add something to potentially confirm this clarification? Outside of personal opinion? Our group came to the same reasoning, because *logically*, it makes some sense, but there was nothing in the rules to clarify what clarifies as a "success".

Comment: In the absence of official ruling/errata to the contrary, the text of the rulebook is all I can offer: and it is clear. Every other reference to "success" includes equality as a success; the brawling section of the rules never uses the word success, only talking about wounding (or not) as the possible outcome. There is no other available interpretation that fits with the body of rules text. The question only comes up based on emergent behavior: the fact that re-rolling a tie might result in a worse outcome for the Martial Artist makes one question the rules. But the rules are clear.

Comment: I've added the rulebook's apparently earlier version of the Martial Artist text as additional evidence.